# Neighborhood of a set iff neighborhood for each point in that set

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Consider the following statement:

A subset $V$ of a topological space $X$ is a neighborhood of the set $S$ if and only if $V$ is a neighborhood for each point in $S$

Here is a proof:

$\color{green}{\large\Rightarrow}$

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $V,S⊆X$, since $V$ is a neighborhood for $S$, by definition of neighborhood of a set there exist an open subset $U$ of $X$such that $S⊆U⊆V$, now choose $x∈S$, using the definition of subset implies  $x∈U⊆V$, based on the definition of neighborhood of a point implies $V$ is a neighborhood for every $x∈S$

for the other direction:

$\color{green}{\large\Leftarrow}$

> Assume for every $x$ is $S$ , $V$ is neighborhood for $x$, using the definition of neighborhood of a point implies there exist an open subset $U_x$ of $X$ such that for every $x∈S$ we have $x∈U_x⊆V$, hence $S = \bigcup_{x \in S} x⊆\bigcup_{x \in S} U_x⊆V$ , since $U_x$ is open in $X$ for every $ x∈S$, hence their union is also open in $X$, using the definition of neighborhood of a set we conclude that $V$ is a neighborhood of the set $S$.

Here the characterization I've used for $U$ is :

$$ \color{blue}{\bigcup_{x \in S} U_x⊆U}\tag{*}$$ 
I don't know if this characterization is right or not,and I think **there is no require** to say $$ \color{blue}{\bigcup_{x \in S} U_x=U}$$ does **always** hold, that's why I use the more general case which I've mentioned in (*).

My question is that can someone check the proof and the definition I've used for $U$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see your problem. You have shown that $S \subset \bigcup_{s \in S} U_x \subset V$ and that the union is open. Now **define** $U  = \bigcup_{s \in S} U_x$. This is an open neighborhood of $S$ as desired.

A perhaps simpler approch is this. Let $U$ denote the interior of $V$. Then $x \in U$ for all $x \in S$ because for each such $x$ there exists an open $U_x$ with $x \in U_x \subset V$, hence in particular $U_x \subset \text{int}V =  U$.
Clearly $S \subset U \subset V$.

Comment: @thank you for your answer, but why we even need to define $U$ such that?even without defining $U$ as you have done the result still follows, I guess you suggest to define $U$ such that because in the first direction we had $S⊆U⊆V$, what will happen if we use the more general case as I did?

Comment: Yes, we do not need to define $U$. I did it because of your formula  $(*)$.

Comment: but in my formula I just defined $U$ such that $\color{blue}{\bigcup_{x \in S} U_x⊆U}$

Comment: That is no definition. What precisely should $U$ be if you work with $\subseteq$ instead of = ?

Comment: well $U$ should be a subset of $V$ which contains all such $U_x$, can you tell me why it's not a definition?

Comment: So you **choose** any $U$ such that $\bigcup U_x \subset U \subset V$? But the only such $U$ which we can be **sure** to satisfy this is $\bigcup U_x$.

Comment: have you any example that does not satisfy my definition? I tried to find but could not

Comment: In genereal there will be many $U$ such that $\bigcup U_x \subset U \subset V$. You can of course say "let us pick one of these". But $U  = \bigcup U_x $ is the simplest choice and the only one you can make explicitly. I am leaving the discussion at this point..